# What is my real Java version on macOS?

Tags: java, macos-sierra

I use macOS Sierra. When I do:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

it seems that my java version is `1.6.0`.
But when I look at `System Preferences` I find that my version is `Java 8 Update 144`. I want to use an R package that needs Java >=8.0. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You might have two different version of java installed, with the one selected by the terminal being the older. Check the path to see where java is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java found in your command line is the one used to compile when using command line, first, try `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` then check if the correct version shows up using `java -version` if not reinstall the newest java and run the command again

Comment: I tried it but "Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"." And I have "Java 8 update 144" but I don't know where.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall? [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) I suspect it being unable to find means it's not installed correctly @sbac

Comment: I had SRE and not SDK installed. Now I think it is installed a new version: "java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)"

Comment: @sbac When you run the version check do you now get the correct version?

Comment: Yes, when I run `java -version` I get 1.8.0_144. I think it's OK.

Comment: Anyone struggling to configure java in macos catalina: remove any JDKs previously installed `sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-<desired version>.jdk`. Download jre and jdk of the same version `jre-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg` and `jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg`.